# how to send data to an independent component in react js

Tags: reactjs

Hello i am new in react js.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import ProductComponent from './Product/productComponent';
import Navbar from './component/NavBar';
import ProductAction from './component/ProductAction';  

class App extends Component {
  state = {  }
  render() { 
    return ( 
      <React.Fragment>
        <Navbar />
        <main className="container">
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/product" exact component={ProductComponent}/>
            <Route path="/product-action" exact component={ProductAction}/>
          </Switch>
        </main>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
 
export default App
```

This is my app component. Here i have used a NavBar component to distribute links and in route i have used  ProductComponent component but ProductComponent is not a child of app component or it may be i don't know. My question is how can i send data to NavBar component from ProductComponent component.
Here is my Navbar component.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

class NavBar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          Navbar
        </a>
        <button
          class="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target="#navbarNav"
          aria-controls="navbarNav"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/product">
                Product
              </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/product-action">
                Product action
              </NavLink>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}

export default NavBar;
```

Comment: Any state management library (like Redux) or (possibly much better in your case) React Context (see React docs for details, there are pretty similar examples).

Comment: I want to pass data between two component without parent child relation. How is it possible? @AdrianoRepetti

Comment: Just read the docs I mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can declare all properties and function of ProductComponent component to App component.
Then passes those to ProductComponent via props. Instead of using

```
<Route path="/product" exact component={ProductComponent}/>
```

We should use

```
<Route 
    path="/product" 
    render={
       props => <ProductComponent products = {this.state.products}/>
    }
/>
```

Since ProductComponent and NavBar component are child of App component we can easily passes all data of ProductComponent to NavBar component via props.

Comment: No, this is exactly what Context API is supposed to avoid because it quickly become a nightmare to maintain. Just use `createContext()` where you want to keep that global state and `useContext()` where you wish to use it. There are really THOUSANDS of examples (including in the docs we all mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the React `useContext` hook to share data between two components

You should check the example from [this documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext).

Or the example [from this tutorial](https://daveceddia.com/usecontext-hook/).

Comment: I want to pass data between two component without parent child relation. How is it possible?